# How to properly make a photo counter, Python

Tags: python, counter

I have a question, I want to make a counter for myself but I have a problem with the code.

```
 # Counter Next button
    self.index = 2  # clicked picture (index number in the list)
    self.counterUp += 1  # counter

 # index images to display: link_to_photo[self.counterSum], e.g. for 0 is self.counterUp = 
 # self.counterSum but for a value other than 0 then the values are different
    self.counterSum = self.counterUp + self.index 

    if self.counterUp < 5:
        print('click, index of photo: ', self.index, 'counter: ', self.counterUp, 'sum: ', self.counterSum)

    else:
        self.counterUp = 0
        self.index = 0
        print('click, index of photo: ', self.index, 'counter: ', self.counterUp, 'sum: ', self.counterSum)
```

results:
for example index = 2 and I have got 5 photos in the dir:

```
click, index of photo:  2 counter:  1 sum:  2  # 1
click, index of photo:  2 counter:  2 sum:  3  # 2
click, index of photo:  2 counter:  3 sum:  4  # 3
click, index of photo:  2 counter:  4 sum:  5  # 4
click, index of photo:  0 counter:  0 sum:  6  # 5
click, index of photo:  2 counter:  1 sum:  2  # 6
click, index of photo:  2 counter:  2 sum:  3  # 7
click, index of photo:  2 counter:  3 sum:  4  # 8
click, index of photo:  2 counter:  4 sum:  5  # 9
```

- index detection works well "click, index of photo"
- I add a counter to the index for each click on "next", "counter". I have 5 pictures so from 0 to 4, ok.
- the problem I have with the "sum".
  line 5 index = 0 counter = 0 gives 6? should be 0 and give from 1 to 4 .

Can ask for help to solve this problem. Thank you very much :D

- The 'print' code is just a test to see what happens

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre], and also carefully think through the logic of the code. Where it says `self.counterUp = 0` and `self.index = 0` and then `print('click, index of photo: ', self.index, 'counter: ', self.counterUp, 'sum: ', self.counterSum)`, that last `print` is the line that gives the wrong output, right? So. The problem is that it shows a wrong value for `self.counterSum`. Right? It's `6`, and you think it should show `0` instead?

Comment: Okay, but **why**? **What part of the code** is supposed to make that happen? That's the `self.counterSum = self.counterUp + self.index` part, right? Okay, but **when** does that happen - before the `print`, or after? Questions like this are not suitable because they are effectively typos; you are expected to be able to *reason through* what the code is doing, and *identify a problem* to ask a question about. If there's still a question here, it's "why doesn't this value become zero before I tell it to?", which doesn't make sense.

Comment: But aside from that, it's useful to show code that other people can **copy and paste, without adding or changing anything**. We shouldn't have to guess that this is inside a loop, and that the loop is inside a function, and that the function is some method of a class. We shouldn't have to guess what kind of thing `self` is, or why we are setting a bunch of attributes on it. (Come to think of it, **do** you want a class here? Why?)

Answer (score 0):

You don't recalculate `counterSum`, it has still the old value.